# Javascript API request - Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, ssl

Hi i'm new to using API's and I have a domain on HTTPS trying to access the data market data on another website [Here](https://api.blockchain.info/charts/market-price?format=json&timespan=30days).  I've tried using localhost and am receiving the same error.

I'm getting the error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.blockchain.info/charts/market-price?format=json&timespan=30days&_=1491089979914. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Is there an easy solution to access this data? Could it be that i need an API key?

```
        //Get Data From JSON Source

        jQuery.ajax({
        url:'https://api.blockchain.info/charts/market-price?format=json&timespan=30days',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,

        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }   
        });
```

Comment: If the API doesn't send CORS headers, there's nothing you can do about it, you have to proxy the request through a service or your webserver.

Comment: please try searching your errors before asking questions. This site, and the web, are full of answers regarding this issue

Comment: You could use [YQL console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) for this and more specific [YQL console/data/json](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+json+where+url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fpipes.yahoo.com%2Fpipes%2Fpipes.popular%3F_out%3Djson%22+and+itemPath+%3D+%22value.items%22) for your case